# Using ng-change and ng-model when wrapping directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-change

Using angular-strap I can use the select directive like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <span class="btn btn-default" disabled>Type:</span>
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-default"
            ng-model="vm.options.type"
            ng-change="vm.doSomething(vm.options)"
            bs-options="o.key as o.label for o in vm.types"
            data-multiple="1"
            bs-select>
    </button>
</div>
```

But I want to wrap this markup in another directive, `my-select`, so I could use it like this:

```
<my-select label="Type"
       ng-model="vm.options.type"
       ng-change="vm.doSomething(vm.options)"
       bs-options="o.key as o.label for o in vm.types">
</my-select>
```

I was able to pass `bs-options` by simply adding element attribute during compile phase of directive, but I can't get `ng-model` and `ng-change` to work the same way it would work without wrapping `bs-select` directive.

I've read how to use `ng-model` in conjunction with `ng-change` by using `ngModelController`, but I would simply like to pass it down to to the wrapped `bs-select` directive.

**EDIT**: Adding directive code
**NOTE**: Code contains different prefix for my directive, I'm aware of that.

```
angular
    .module('ticketApp.ui')
    .directive('ttSelect', ttSelect);

function ttSelect() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        bindToController: {
            label: '@ttLabel',
            ngModel: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'ui/tt-select/tt-select.html',
        controller: ttSelectController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        link: link,
        compile: compile
    };

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function () {
            console.log('changed');
        });
    }

    function compile(element, attrs) {
        var bsOptions = document.createAttribute('bs-options');
        var bsSelect = element.children()[1];

        bsOptions.nodeValue = attrs.ttOptions;
        bsSelect.attributes.setNamedItem(bsOptions);
    }
}

function ttSelectController() {
    this.label = 'Label';
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for the directive.

Comment: May be you want to use transclusion ?

Comment: Just updated the question with source code.
@OleksandrPapchenko I thought about transclusion, but that does not look as nice as I would like it to be.
I've found some workaround for the problem by simply passing my own expressions as `on-change` for example, but then I have to do some extra work on the controllers.

Comment: I think we need isolated scope here. in such a way we would be able to use values from isolated scope directly in our template 'ui/tt-select/tt-select.html', for ng-model and bs-select etc... Also we will be able to have sveral instances of directive for different datasets at the same time, without modifiing directieve template at the compile phase. I think using isolated scope is more Angular way.